# Optimization of update batch operation on Hbase

Tags: hbase, cron-task

I have two master tables (say tabl1, tabl2) in hbase containing the 34874716 and 25167890 rows respectively. Now on a daily basis two temporary tables gets generated containing the 2-2.5 lac rows. I have one [cron job](http://autofei.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/java-example-code-using-hbase-data-model-operations/) to update the temporary table rows into master tables. Which takes around 4.5-5 hours. Algorithm of cron job to update the master table is that it fetch the row from master table one by one if exists and update the same else it insert the row in table.

FYI, I have this cron job running on the same machine on which one of the `region servers` of `hbase` is running. I want to minimize the time of this cron job as well as memory utilization. So, is there any better approach than suggested in above link of cron job?

Comment: Why does the cron job check if the record exists? HBase works natively the same way. If you insert records for a row key which is already present, it is updated, but if it is a new one, it is inserted.

Comment: No, I need to update records means i need to do some manipulation on  the values. Hbase will not do it for me own its own, right?